# How to enter data directly to make a data.frame representing a contingency table?

Tags: r, contingency

I'm trying to directly enter the following data into **R** (which represents a contingency table)

```
Area        School    Coffeshop    Hospitals    Parks    Totatl  
Washington     142          120           20       20       302   
Seattle        120          140           30       40       330 
Total          262          260           50       60       632
```

My code is this:

```
n<-c("Area","School","Cofeeshop","Hospitals","Parks","Total") 
x<-c("Washington",142,120,20,20,302)
y<-c("Seattle",120,140,30,40,330)
z<-c("Total",262,260,50,60,631)
data<-cbind(n,x,y,z)
data<-data.frame(data)
```

Comment: @Joran It's in the R 2.15.2 release :P

Comment: oops. typo. was supposed to be "data<-data.form(data)"!!

Comment: Out of the frying pan...

Comment: @TylerRinker Not sure if that would be Trick or Treat.

Comment: @Marine getting warmer.  `data.frame`  I voted to close as this is a typing error or lack of familiarity with beginning R.  This [Intro to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) was helpful to me when I started out.

Comment: could you explain why R wouldn't import the names in the table though? I can't find it anywhere in my book!

Comment: You can skip `cbind`. Try `data.frame(n = n,x = x,y = y,z = z)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is full of basic syntax errors, please try and copy-and-paste directly from the script you are using. (I really hope you have not done this here).

If you combine character and numeric variables in the same vector, it will create a character vector, which is not what you want.

Try something like

```
vec_names <-c("School", "Cofeeshop", "Hospitals", "Parks", "Total") 
Washington <- c(142, 120, 20, 20, 302)
Seattle<-c(120, 140, 30, 40, 330)
Total <-  c(262, 260, 50, 60, 631)

ctable <- rbind(Washington, Seattle, Total)
colnames(ctable) <- vec_names

# ctable is a matrix at the moment, with the rownames identifying 
# Washington etc

ctable_df <- data.frame(ctable)

# ctable_df is now a data.frame.
# if you want area as a column in your data.frame (not just row.names)
CTABLE <- data.frame(area= rownames(ctable_df), ctable_df, row.names = NULL)
CTABLE
        area School Cofeeshop Hospitals Parks Total
1 Washington    142       120        20    20   302
2    Seattle    120       140        30    40   330
3      Total    262       260        50    60   631
```

Answer (score 2):

Using tribble from tidyverse
(see [tidyverse tibble](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/) for more details)

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
ctable <-
tribble(
  ~Area, ~School, ~Coffeeshop, ~Hospitals, ~Parks, ~Total,
  "Washington", 142, 120, 20, 20, 302,
  "Seattle", 120, 140, 30, 40, 330,
  "Total", 262, 260, 50, 60, 631
)
ctable
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Area       School Coffeeshop Hospitals Parks Total
  <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Washington    142        120        20    20   302
2 Seattle       120        140        30    40   330
3 Total         262        260        50    60   631
```

Comment: Cool! Didn't know about tribble() - and needed it! Perfect.

Comment: together with uncount() - to make tidy data. My life is now complete.